# PHP Get Token Oauth PKCE

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth, pkce

I want to get token from Oauth server. I log in the browser using username and password and Oauth server return this url:

[http:/example.com/callback?code=D3F7A9B42EA49F92EACC21ECC60AA7187A71DAD85E4478FB8724BB0444054D39&scope=tts_api&iss=https://oauthserver.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

for handle this callback i used from this method

```
    public function handleAauth(Request $request)
    {
        $http = new Client;
        $code_verifier = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
        $code_challenge = hash('sha256', $code_verifier, true);

        $response = $http->post('https://outh-server.com/connect/token', [
          'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 'my-client-id',
            'code_verifier' => $code_verifier,
            'code' => $request->code,
            'code_challenge' => $code_challenge,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
          ],
          'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']
        ]);

        return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }
```

when use this code for callback, return this error:

```
Client error: `POST https://outh-server.com/connect/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_request"}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What types of `Content-Type` are allowed?

Comment: json But it doesn't matter for the test (edited question and added headers)

Comment: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/: _"The technique involves the client first creating a secret on each authorization request, and then using that secret again when exchanging the authorization code for an access token."_ - you appear to be _creating_ a new secret here, when you try to perform the _second_ step - so that of course can't work. You need to supply the _same_ `code_verifier` and `code_challenge` values that you already used in your authorization request.

Comment: You may want to look into Laravel Socialite. It may have the provider you are looking for and it's a breeze to get everything setup.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `json` key instead of `form_params` to send the request payload as a JSON object.

```
public function handleAauth(Request $request)
{
    $http = new Client;
    $code_verifier = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    $code_challenge = hash('sha256', $code_verifier, true);

    $response = $http->post('https://outh-server.com/connect/token', [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'json' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 'my-client-id',
            'code_verifier' => $code_verifier,
            'code' => $request->code,
            'code_challenge' => $code_challenge,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
        ]
    ]);

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Try adding more specific error handling to your code to get more information about the error response. For example, you could catch the `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` exception and inspect the response body and headers:

```
try {
    // Make API request
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    // Get response details
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $reasonPhrase = $response->getReasonPhrase();
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    // Log error details or handle the error in some other way
}
```

Comment: thanks. but using this code the problem still exists.

Comment: Double-check the client ID and redirect URI to ensure they match what is registered with the OAuth server. Answer update to catch the error